# Having trouble specifying wanted data to scrape via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.deribit.com/main#/options?tab=all"
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
```

I'm trying to grab all the data on the bottom of the page where it says "Recent Trades CALLS" and "Recent Trades PUTS". I have tried variations of:

```
soup.find_all(div', {'class': 'row'})
soup.find_all('tbody')
```

But to no avail. To clarify I would like to grab the entire tables' worth of data including all the columns like (Assets, Price, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is dynamic data, is is not contained in the page you request but gets loaded by javascript after initial page load... you see 3 blue dots working in the middle of the screen while actually getting the data, you have 2 options for this:

1. Use Chrom/Firefox dev tools to snoop on the network pane for the calls to get the data you want and try to emulate those calls, cookies, headers, parameters, all.
2. Use an actual browser that will load the full page before scraping it, for this you can use selenium